# Remove posts_orderby filter then add it back in

Tags: loop, filters

I'm using

```
  remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
```

to remove the order for a query. For a query further down the page I need the filter back.

How do I add it back in?

Answer (score 1):

To add back the filters that were removed you'd have to know what was hooked in originally in the first place. You could crawl the `global` `$wp_filter` array, but this should do the same at far less effort:

```
function remove_query_order($order) {
  remove_filter('posts_orderby','remove_query_order',PHP_INT_MAX);
  return '';
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','remove_query_order',PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Add the filter before the query you want it to effect and it will remove itself.